# How to read web response

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream, tcpclient

I am not being able to read the source of a site via Tcp Client.

Please don't tell me you can read the source via httpwebrequest, webclient or http client - I do not want to use those methods.

I can read the headers response, but I can't read html response.

Here is my code:

```
Dim address As String = " Write your site here "

Dim tcp As TcpClient = New TcpClient(address, 80)
Dim o As NetworkStream = tcp.GetStream

Dim buffer() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1" + vbCrLf + "Host: " + address + vbCrLf + vbCrLf)
o.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

Dim xbytes(tcp.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte

o.Read(xbytes, 0, tcp.ReceiveBufferSize)

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(xbytes))

MsgBox("Done")
```

The header response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: proxygen-bolt
Date: Thu, 07 May 2020 19:39:59 GMT
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
Content-Language: en
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 11351
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

The problem is I can't read the html response, I can only read the headers response.

Comment: `Dim xbytes(2024) As Byte` - are 2025 bytes enough for the entire response? Has the server even sent the entire response in the short time before the code reads it?

Comment: I know that 2024 are not enough! I changed the bytes to more than 100000! I can read the response via windows telnet, But it doesn't work via tcp client!

Comment: I can read entire response through windows telnet

Comment: Is there code missing where you read the stream until it ends?

Comment: Have you tried to use `StreamReader` and `GetStream` method of  `TcpClient`?

Comment: Yes, I have used StreamReader and GetStream ! Same problem

Comment: I have changed the server, Same problem

Comment: @Killer Please [edit] your question to add the code which uses a StreamReader, in case we can spot a problem there.